# Compare domains in php

Tags: php

I wrote a small script that provided a URL (For example: code.google.com/ajax/123/1235/214)
Would tell you that the actual domain is: code.google.com

When this is compared to code.google.com it return true of course, i want it to return true when it is compared to (anything).google.com
So, i want it to return true whenever the actual domain is the same regardless of the subdomain, how to do that?

(This is NOT a homework question, it is for a project I am working on so please provide as much help as possible)

(if you need more information to understand the problem, please write a comment and I will provide more information immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution might be to use something like [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) to extract the `host` portion of your URL *(that's probably the easiest way to get that information)*.

Then, you can [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) that host, using '`.`' as separator, to get an array that contains the components of the URL *(for instance, you'd have `array('code', 'google', 'com')`)*

And, finally, only compare the last two elements of the array you have for each URL.

That way, you'd compare '`google`' and '`com`' with the informations from the second URL.

I suppose just using a couple of *(simpler)* string comparisons might work in some cases ; but don't forget cases like '`www.mywebsite.com`' and '`subdomain.website.com`' *-- just an example to show that comparing end of domain names is not enough ^^*

Comment: is there a way to compare google.com to google.co.uk for example and still return true?

Answer (score 1):

It could use some error checking but you can do something like this:

```
<?php

function url_belongs_to_domain($url, $domain){
    $url_domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

    return preg_match('/' . preg_quote($domain, '/') . '$/i', $url_domain)==1;
}

var_dump( url_belongs_to_domain('http://code.google.com/ajax/123/1235/214', 'google.com') );
var_dump( url_belongs_to_domain('http://code.google.com/ajax/123/1235/214', 'code.google.com') );
var_dump( url_belongs_to_domain('http://code.google.com/ajax/123/1235/214', 'www.google.com') );
var_dump( url_belongs_to_domain('http://www.google.com/ajax/123/1235/214', 'google.com') );
var_dump( url_belongs_to_domain('http://www.google.com/ajax/123/1235/214', 'code.google.com') );
var_dump( url_belongs_to_domain('http://www.google.com/ajax/123/1235/214', 'www.google.com') );

?>

bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

Be aware that accurate detection of top level domains requires checking against a list since it doesn't follow any rule: in **www.google.com** it is **google.com**, in **www.google.co.uk** it is **google.co.uk**.